# Rails replace case block with guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building scoring system where user, depends on his correct answers, will pass or fail the test. Depends of user experience there are 3 criterias: institutional users always passed, experts will pass when they have more than 3 scoring_points, beginners have to have 5 scoring_points (100%). To do so I've create case block:

```
def set_status(scoring_points)
  case experience_level
  when 'institutional'
    'passed'
  when 'beginner'
    scoring_points == 5 ? 'passed' : 'failed' && increase_failed_attempts
  when 'expert'
    scoring_points >= 3 ? 'passed' : 'failed' && increase_failed_attempts
  end
end
```

Because of CyclomaticComplexity I'm wondering is there a better, cleaner way to replace that case block? maybe I could use guard somehow?

Comment: `'failed' && increase_failed_attempts` in this snippet 'failed' is void. Should it be returned?

Comment: nope, `increase_failed_attempts` just increments `failed_attempts` fields -       `user.increment!(:failed_attempts, 1)`

Comment: Note however that `&&` operator in this case ALWAYS returns whatever is returned by `increase_failed_attempts` , i.e. the second operand, as the first operand is always truethy.

Comment: `experience_level` is not a second argument?

Comment: nope, this values comes from a different model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to restructure the code depending on what you can assume about the `scoring_points` and `experience_level`.

For example, if `scoring_points` is a number that is capped at five then you could say:

```
PASS = {
  'beginner' => 5,
  'expert'   => 3,
}.freeze
def set_status(scoring_points)
  return 'passed' if(!PASS[experience_level] || scoring_points >= PASS[experience_level])
  increase_failed_attempts
  'failed'
end
```

since `scoring_points == 5` and `scoring_points >= 5` would be equivalent.

You could remove the `!PASS[experience_level]` check with a `#to_i` call since `nil.to_i == 0`:

```
PASS = {
  'beginner' => 5,
  'expert'   => 3,
}.freeze
def set_status(scoring_points)
  return 'passed' if(scoring_points >= PASS[experience_level].to_i)
  increase_failed_attempts
  'failed'
end
```

And if you know that `experience_level` will always be one of the three values in your case then you could add an explicit `PASS` entry for `'institutional'` instead of the `#to_i` call:

```
PASS = {
  'institutional' => 0,
  'beginner'      => 5,
  'expert'        => 3,
}.freeze
def set_status(scoring_points)
  return 'passed' if(scoring_points >= PASS[experience_level])
  increase_failed_attempts
  'failed'
end
```

You could also use [`Kernel#then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-then) to more or less supply your own return value for the `increase_failed_attempts` call:

```
PASS = {
  'institutional' => 0,
  'beginner'      => 5,
  'expert'        => 3,
}.freeze
def set_status(scoring_points)
  return 'passed' if(scoring_points >= PASS[experience_level])
  increase_failed_attempts.then { 'failed' }
end
```

With that in place you could replace the guard:

```
PASS = {
  'institutional' => 0,
  'beginner'      => 5,
  'expert'        => 3,
}.freeze
def set_status(scoring_points)
  scoring_points >= PASS[experience_level] ? 'passed' : increase_failed_attempts.then { 'failed' }
end
```

I'd probably end up with the third or fourth options.

Answer (score 3):

To pass CyclomaticComplexity you can use a simple condition.

```
def set_status(scoring_points)
  if (experience_level == 'institutional') ||
     (experience_level == 'beginner' && scoring_points == 5) ||
     (experience_level == 'expert' && scoring_points >= 3)
    'passed'
  else
    increase_failed_attempts
    'failed'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think making this a method is a mistake. The problem is that the 'institutional' experience level is treated differently than the other two; specifically, there is no `scoring_points` associated with 'institutional'. When the reader sees `set_status(scoring_points)` (or perhaps it should be `set_status(experience_level, scoring_points)`) the presumption is that the argument is needed.

One could write `def set_status(experience_level, scoring_points = nil)` and call `set_status('institutional')`, but that is still *hokey* (noticeably contrived), so should be avoided. Better, in my opinion, is to replace the call to `set_status` with one of the following.

**#1**

```
PASS_RANGES = { 'beginner' => 5..5, 'expert' => 3.. }

case experience_level
when 'institutional'
  'passed'
when 'beginner', 'expert'
  if PASS_RANGES.cover?(scoring_points)
    'passed'
  else
    increase_failed_attempts
    'failed'
  end
else
  # raise exception
end
```

You could freeze `PASS_RANGES` if you like, though I don't see the need to do so.

I expected `increase_failed_attempts` to have `experience_level` as an argument, leading me to wonder if some refactoring may be called for.

**#2**

```
case experience_level
when 'institutional'
  'passed'
when 'beginner', 'expert'
  if beginner_or_expert_pass?(experience_level, scoring_points)
    'passed'
  else
    increase_failed_attempts
    'failed'
  end
else
  # raise exception
end
```

```
def beginner_or_expert_pass?(experience_level, scoring_points)
  (experience_level == 'beginner' && scoring_points == 5) ||
  (experience_level == 'expert' && scoring_points >= 3)
end
```